# Deploy to azure website and run grunt build tasks

Tags: node.js, azure, continuous-integration

I am trying to get continuous integration working for my Azure website which uses grunt, npm and bower to build.

I have followed the instructions here: http://www.cptloadtest.com/2013/12/03/Git-And-Grunt-Deploy-To-Windows-Azure.aspx and have modified my deploy.sh deployment section to match.

When I deploy I get the following error message:

```
Command: bash deploy.sh
Handling node.js grunt deployment.
 An error has occurred during web site deployment.
C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\45.40522.1562\bin\scripts\selectNodeVersion.js:115
select node version failed
    throw new Error('Usage: node.exe selectNodeVersion.js <path_to_repo> <path
          ^
Error: Usage: node.exe selectNodeVersion.js <path_to_repo> <path_to_wwwroot> [path_to_temp]
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\45.40522.1562\bin\scripts\selectNodeVersion.js:115:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Does anybody know what I could try next?

Answer (score 0):

I also had some problems doing build and deployment in visual studio online. I added a command line "npm.cmd cache clean" at the top of my build definition. That made it work. Maybe that helps you too.